# how to check mark all checkbocxes by selecting one checkbox

Tags: javascript

i have written code like this to select all the check boxes in the fetched data

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" />
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
?> 
<tr>
 <td><span><?php echo $row["id"] ?></span></td>
<td><span><?php echo $row["emailid"] ?></span></td>
<td><span class="wrapper"><input type="checkbox" name="sendmsg[]"  value="<?php echo $row["emailid"] ?>"/></span></td>
</tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

i have written java script like this

```
  $('#select-all').click(function(event) {   
    if(this.checked) {
    // Iterate each checkbox
    $('#sendmsg[]').each(function() {
        this.checked = true;                        
       });
        }
      });
```

how to write corect script to get all the check boxes selected

Comment: Your html is not valid as it is, you cannot have input-element and tr-element as siblings.

Comment: i hav added new code plezse try this way

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggle(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkbox[]');
    if (x = 1) {
        for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  onClick="toggle(this)" />
<input name="checkbox[]"    type="checkbox"  >
<input name="checkbox[]"    type="checkbox"  >
<input name="checkbox[]"    type="checkbox"  >
```

**Try this**

```js
function toggle(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('sendmsg[]');
    
        for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++)        {
            checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        
       }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" onClick="toggle(this)" />
        <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
    ?> 
    <tr>
     <td><span><?php echo $row["id"] ?></span></td>
    <td><span><?php echo $row["emailid"] ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="wrapper"><input type="checkbox" name="sendmsg[]"  value="<?php echo $row["emailid"]; ?></span></td>
    </tr>
     <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

get element by its **name** if you are using # then its element by id

```
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {   
    if(this.checked) {
    // Iterate each checkbox
    $('[name="sendmsg[]"]').each(function() {
        this.checked = true;                        
       });
        }
      });
```